# Tyrus websocket handshake error

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

I am using

compile group: 'org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles', name: 'tyrus-standalone-client', version: '1.13'

My server is up and running, but my client fails to connect sometimes.With the following error.
This is for a chat app.

**Code** :

```
    public void connect(final MessageHandler.Whole<String> messageHandler){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    session = container.connectToServer(new Endpoint() {
                        @Override
                        public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
                            session.addMessageHandler(messageHandler);
                        }
                    },ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build(),URI.create(url));
                } catch (DeploymentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

**StackTrace** : 03-28 09:31:02.023 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake response not received.
03-28 09:31:02.023 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:699)
03-28 09:31:02.023 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:717)
03-28 09:31:02.033 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
03-28 09:31:02.033 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-28 09:31:02.033 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:871)
03-28 09:31:02.033 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:81)
03-28 09:31:02.033 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:516)
03-28 09:31:02.033 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:360)
03-28 09:31:02.033 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at com.cooey.maya.WebSocketConnector$1.run(WebSocketConnector.java:48)
03-28 09:31:02.033 17028-17604/com.biz.health.anycare W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: that's a connection timeout - are you sure that the server sent a response? If you need, you can extend this timeout (default is 30 seconds or something like that) by setting property https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.13/org/glassfish/tyrus/client/ClientManager.html#HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT

Comment: How do you know its timeout exception ? I am not understanding

Comment: I'm one of the authors, so I just know. "Handshake response not received." is the basic protection of the client "connect" - there is a countdown latch which expires after connect timeout and if the handshate response is not received, it results with the exception you are seeing.

Comment: @PavelBucek You should not have conflated these two conditions. If it's a connect timeout, say so: if the connection succeeded but there is a response timeout, say that. They mean quite different things. First means the host is down: second means the host is *up* but slow.